# Routing with pfSense

Tags: vmware-esxi, routing, virtual-machines, pfsense

I have inherited a badly designed network, and have to keep it up. There's a machine running VMWare, and a pfSense VMWare appliance is acting as firewall and NAT. The network in use inside this NAT is 10.0.0.0/14. The pfSense appliance has two more network adapters, one connected to the internet, and one connected to another physical machine on a 10.139.251.104/29 network. What I am tasked with is to make that external machine visible to other virtual machines running behind pfSense. I have been banging my head against the wall, trying to figure out what sort of a rule do I need to create in pfSense and other VMS (which are running CentOS) to make this happen. Can anyone give me any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to expose some services running on the external machine then you could use Port Forwarding.

pfSense has a very straightforward web interface for doing that.

Comment: My problem is, how can I instruct the VMs to send packets destined for 10.139.251.107 to 10.0.0.1 (the gateway) because at the moment they don't. I have tried adding a route like this: `route add -net 10.139.251.104/29 10.0.0.1` but when I try `traceroute 10.139.251.107` it doesn't go through 10.0.0.1

Comment: Try this:

route add -net 10.139.251.104 NETMASK 255.255.255.248 gw 10.0.0.1